# using python subprocess to a get directory size on mac instead of os.walk

Tags: python, macos, shell, directory, subprocess

I am relatively new to python and the subprocess module.

I'm trying to get a directories size with python using a subprocess on mac osx. os.walk takes a long time for large directories. I am hoping to get subprocess to do this with a shell command and speed up the result. this shell command works for me but i cannot get it to work from subprocess?

( cd /test_folder_path && ls -nR | grep -v '^d' | awk '{total += $5} END {print total}' )

This is how I am trying to create the subprocess in python.

```
import shlex 
import subprocess

target_folder = "/test_folder_path"
command_line = "( cd " + target_folder + " && ls -nR | grep -v '^d' | awk '{total += $5} END {print total}' )"
args = shlex.split(command_line)
print args
folder_size = subprocess.check_output(args)
print str(folder_size)
```

in python i get the following errors when the subprocess.check_ouput is called

folder_size = subprocess.check_output(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in **init**
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

when I use the same directory in the shell command it works and gives me the directories correct size.

any help with making this approach work or pointing me to a better method would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong? Python error? Cmd line syntax error? Wrong answer?

Comment: Try `cd /test_folder_path && du -c | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python's subprocess defaults to using `shell=False`.  In order to run the subcommand with the pipes, you *need the shell* to prevent python from interpreting the pipes (and `&&`) as arguments to `cd`.

```
target_folder = "/test_folder_path"
command_line = "cd " + target_folder + " && ls -nR | grep -v '^d' | awk '{total += $5} END {print total}'"
folder_size = subprocess.check_output(command_line, shell=True)
```

I've tried the above, only using the command suggested by drewk:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> folder_size = subprocess.check_output('cd ~/mydir && du -c | tail -n 1', shell=True)
>>> folder_size
b'113576\ttotal\n'
```

and all seems to be well.

As noted in the comments, `subprocess.Popen` (and by extension, `check_output`) also accepts a `cwd` argument which is the directory to run your command from.  This eliminates the need to do any changing of directory in your command:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> result = subprocess.check_output('du -c | tail -n 1', cwd='/path/to/home/mydir', shell=True)
>>> result
'113576\ttotal\n'
```

Comment: Great answer but can be further refined by skipping `"cd " + target_folder + " && "` in favor of using the 'cwd' param to check_output.

Comment: @tdelaney -- Brilliant.  I've never had the need to use that keyword before.  That's just wonderful.

Comment: @drewk -- Of course, at this point, thanks to the great suggestion by tdelaney, we would probably be better off removing the pipe to `tail` and just reading the output stream from python (keeping the last line).  Then we can once again eliminate the shell.

Comment: @mgilson: `we would probably be better off removing the pipe to tail and just reading the output stream from python (keeping the last line)` even better still. I was mainly reacting to the OP trying to parse `ls` with `grep`. Since UNIX allows almost any character including whitespace and new lines in a file name, parsing ls is problematic... Thanks